# Grep a value from array in terraform and the occurence as a count in terraform

Tags: terraform

Trying to setup multiple subnets in multiple vpcs
What is the interpolation syntaz for filtering the number of occurences of a keyword and setting that up as a count in terraform

tfvars file format is

```
"subnets"
        "0:10.3.0.0/24:private",
        "0:10.3.1.0/24:private",
        "1:10.3.2.0/24:public",
        "1:10.3.3.0/24:private"
```

- 2 private subnets in VPC 0
- 1 public, 1 private in VPC 1

Plan is to have one module for private subnet and the other for public subnet.

VPC is created by another module.

In `public_subnet/main.tf` file - Plan is initiate a counter to grep for public `var.subnets` in the tfvars file and start the counter ( In our case 1) and loop through the `vpc_id` generated by the VPC modules (Another challenge is how to correlate which ID is which vpc).

In `private_subnet/main.tf` - Grep for private keyword in `var.subnets`, start the counter and loop through the `vpc_id`.

How do I format the interpolation sequence for such a need?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't currently possible but will be possible in `0.12`. You can [filter for exact values](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16550#issuecomment-363961932) but not substrings.

Comment: Thank you for your response .. Can i export the output  vpc_ids into a map but specific keywords tieing each vpc_ic to each keywork ... so that i can call them later the vpc_ids for nat gateway , igw , security groups  etc .   But Map does not support count yet .. so it need to be hard coded ... but again it beats the purpose of automation since if i increase the number of subnets and i have go in and change the code to include those  ... Thinking of a simpler way

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this using terraform 0.12.x

```hcl
variable "subnets" {
  default = [
    "0:10.3.0.0/24:private",
    "0:10.3.1.0/24:private",
    "1:10.3.2.0/24:public",
    "1:10.3.3.0/24:private"
  ]
}

locals {
  # return the second element in the array which is the IP/CIDR if the vpc is "0"
  subnets_zero = [
    for subnet in var.subnets:
      split(":", subnet)[1]
      if split(":", subnet)[0] == "0"
  ]
  # return the second element in the array which is the IP/CIDR if the vpc is "1"
  subnets_one = [
    for subnet in var.subnets:
      split(":", subnet)[1]
      if split(":", subnet)[0] == "1"
  ]
}

output "subnets_zero" {
  value = local.subnets_zero
}

output "subnets_one" {
  value = local.subnets_one
}
```

```sh
$ terraform apply
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

subnets_one = [
  "10.3.2.0/24",
  "10.3.3.0/24",
]
subnets_zero = [
  "10.3.0.0/24",
  "10.3.1.0/24",
]
```